# Selenium using the old page after browser back button action and not showing alterations to DOM

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following pages:

=========== mytestpage1.htm ===========

```html
<p>This is my test page 1</p>
<input id="mysearch" type="image" onclick="return searchClick();" src="../../Img/arrow_large_down.gif" />
<span id="generatingResults" style="font-weight:bold;DISPLAY: none">Generating results...</span>
<script>
    function searchClick() {
        document.getElementById("generatingResults").style.display = 'block';
        location.href = 'mytestpage2.htm';
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

=========== mytestpage2.htm ===========

```html
<p><b>This is my test page 2</b></p>
```

I am performing the following action:

1. Clicking "mysearch button" so that mytestpage2.htm loads
2. Click the browser back button to return to mytestpage1.htm
3. Confirm that I can see the string "Generating results..."

If I test manually with Firefox 12.0 I see the string displayed.

However when I use Selenium the string does not display.
Here are the basic Selenium test steps: (browser is OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver and the test uses Firefox 12.0)

```java
browser.FindElementById("mysearch").Click();
browser.Navigate().Back();
var canBeSeen = browser.FindElementById("generatingResults").GetCssValue("display") == "block";
```

canBeSeen is set to false (I am using version 2.33.0.0 of Selenium on .NET 4.0)

I found these links that seem related:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3611
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2181

Does anyone know why I am encountering the above problem with trying to simulate the browser back button using Selenium?

If so, how can I fix it so that canBeSeen is set to true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After the execution what is the value of canBeSeen ?

Comment: Can you please show me the HTML of "generatingResults" string

Comment: The HTML is posted above in my question...see mytestpage1.htm...It stays the same before and after the test runs.

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding,When back button is clicked it will freshly load the mytestpage1.htm where the generatingResults is hidden.i.e,your previous transaction was not persisted.If you are using any server side scripting, then have someother solutions. For now, try the following.
Set a cookie object while moving to next page,then depends the cookie value set the display property of your string while you are coming back.

[Check here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) if you are new to Cookies

change your searchClick method as follows,

```
function searchClick() {

   // check your cookie variable whether to display or not use a if condition 
     document.getElementById("generatingResults").style.display = 'block';
    location.href = 'mytestpage2.htm';
   // if it is the first time you are visiting this page, That is your cookie object is null, then set a value.
    return false;
}
```